# how to add an element to a jquery array?

Tags: jquery

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdobWy

both return 0

**what do i want?**

that it returns 1.

that I can use

```
x.each(function(i, el){...});
```

to code with it

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdobWy

```
$(function($){
  var x = $([]);
  x.add('biippo');
  console.error(x.length); // returns 0

  x[0] = 'foo';
  console.error(x.length); // returns 0
});
```

Comment: `$()` will create a jquery object from a selector like `var $divs = $('div');` If you want an array, use `var x =  [];` then you can do something like `x.push('biippo');` and to loop you can do `$.each(x, function(index, element){ //.....});`

Comment: funny how the SO droids down vote without having a) an understanding of the issue and b) any idea of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "push" instead of "add".

Try this `x.push('biippo');` instead of `x.add('biippo');`

[Please check the updated fiddle.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaEOre)

```js
$(function($){
  var x = $([]);
  x.push('biippo');
  console.error(x.length);
  
  x[0] = 'foo';
  console.error(x.length);
  
  $.each(x, function(index, element){ console.log(element); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might also mention that `x.each(function(i, el){...});` would be incorrect. and that the correct syntax would be `$.each(x, function(index, element){ //.....});` since the op has an array and not a jquery collection

Comment: yes, thanks for that.

Comment: @DelightedD0D might to share info? because `x.each` very well works. Did you see I did `var x = $([]);` ?

Comment: sure, the difference is that [$.each() or jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is "A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays." While [$(selector).each( function )](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is "designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object" The way you have it will "seem" to work, but it is not intended for arrays

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this sequence will help :

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var x = $(arr); // form a jQuery collection
console.log(x.length); // 3

arr.push('d'); // push 'd' onto the original array
console.log(x.length); // still 3 (x is not a 'live' representation of arr)

x = x.add('d'); // select DOM element with tagName 'd'
console.log(x.length); // still 3 (no DOM element was selected)

x.add($(['d'])); // merge a new jQuery collection with x
console.log(x.length); // still 3 (.add() returns a new jQuery selection containing 4 elements, but leaves x unchanged)

x = x.add($(['d'])); // merge a new jQuery collection with x, and assign to x
console.log(x.length); // 4 (.add() returns a new jQuery selection containing 4 elements, and x is changed by assignment).
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xoy8qge4/)**

Comment: Honestly, I feel like the .add examples will just confuse the OP more, maybe you could use actual selectors

Comment: @DelightedD0D, that is indeed a danger. I was just trying to reflect what the OP appeared to be attempting.